# How to open HG repository browser from command prompt for a specific file?

Tags: mercurial

I know about hgtk log command but it is working for directory not for a file.

If I execute something like this

```
hgtk log -R D:\bmutilities\big_repo\chrome\content\br_editor.js
```

It throws an error saying---directory not found

But if run hgtk command in `D:\bmutilities\big_repo\chrome\content\` directory

```
hgtk log -R br_editor.js
```

it works fine...

Suggestions please ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `--repository` or `-R` option to specify the path to the repository. After that, the filenames are **relative** to that directory. In this sense, `hgtk -R` works like `hg --cwd` meaning that it actually changes the current working directory.

Mercurial also has a `--repository` (`-R`) command like switch, but this does not change the current working directory of the process.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I understand your question better now.  You mean that you cannot view the history of a file from the command line if you are not *in* a folder under the .hg root folder.

That appears to be a design decision by mercurial.

I just make sure I cd to a folder inside the repo before I do `hgtk log` on a specific file.

Comment: so should I do something like this ..

hgExe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
hgExe.initWithPath("C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].
          createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
blocking = true;
process.init(hgExe)
args = ["D:"];
process.run(blocking,args,args.length);
args = ["CD", "D:\\my_repo\\"];
process.run(blocking,args,args.length);
args = ["hgtk","log",fileName];
process.run(blocking,args,args.length);

Comment: @Nitesh; yes... but that's hard to read;  I would just say:  'In your script, first change directory to the repo root, and then do the hgtk log'  :)

Comment: sorry about that...I am executing process.run() again and again with different arguments assuming it will keep track of previous process...am I making any sense ?

process.run(true,["cd","d:\myrepo\"],2];

process.run(true,["hgtk","log","myfile.txt"],3);

Now is it clear what I mean ?